# MySQL Missing operand near Like

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to filter a datagridview by the ID number, It keeps throwing an error ('Missing operand before 'Like' operator')

I keep getting this error only when filtering by a table ID column. It works fine if I filter by ('First_Name') or anything else but will not let me filter by ID.  Any ideas?

```
Me.WelderNamesTableAdapter.FillBy(MacroQualityDataSet.welderNames)
    Me.WelderNamesBindingSource.Filter = ("CONVERT(welderID, System.String) + [welderID] + LIKE + '%" & welderIDtxtbx.Text & "%'")
```

Comment: What error are you getting and what do you expect to get?

Comment: I am trying to filter a datagridview by the ID number, It keeps throwing an error ('Missing operand before 'Like' operator')

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to add a graphic to this question. Please [edit] to remove it, and add the error message as text. The graphic is difficult to read, it's almost useless when seen from a mobile device, it wastes data for those users that are using a mobile device, and images are often blocked by corporate proxies, making the information unavailable to those readers. Image content is also not searchable, so it's unavailable for future readers searching for an answer to a similar problem. Use images only when needed to present a problem that can't be demonstrated without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The + is not helping you here if welderID is a number that will not work.
This might

```
  Me.WelderNamesTableAdapter.FillBy(MacroQualityDataSet.welderNames)
      Me.WelderNamesBindingSource.Filter = ("CONVERT(System.String,welderID) LIKE + '%" & welderIDtxtbx.Text & "%'")
```

Comment: Now it is throwing this with your reccommendation:             An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The expression contains undefined function call VARCHAR().

Comment: OK - maybe System.String will do it.

Comment: Still the same thing, if it makes any difference welderID is a foreign key on this table, Can I not filter by keys?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with foreign keys - that seems to be a syntax error you are getting.

Comment: If I use  Me.WelderNamesBindingSource.Filter = ("welderID like '%" & welderIDtxtbx.Text & "%'") I get this error:                              Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String. If I change the name of the column to say First_Name it works completely fine.  I can't figure out why.

Comment: Yep - you need to convert the integer to a string. You could try   (" ''+welderID like '%" & welderIDtxtbx.Text & "%'")